# How to unset max-height?

Tags: css

How to I reset the `max-height` property to its default, if it has been previously set in some CSS rule? This doesn't work:

```
pre {
  max-height: 250px;
}

pre.doNotLimitHeight {
  max-height: auto; // Doesn't work at least in Chrome
}
```

Answer (score 383, accepted):

Reset it to `none`:

```
pre {
  max-height: 250px;
}

pre.doNotLimitHeight {
  max-height: none;
}
```

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-height)**

Comment: Just a note that this doesn't work for `min-height` (`none` is not allowed and results in the value not being overriden).

Comment: @Jon That's right, the default value for `min-height` is 0, but since "Infinity" isn't a thing in CSS, `max-height` defaults to `none`.

Comment: Thanks, I used this to un-set `max-width`... funny thing about CSS is that you don't know whether to use `inherit`, `auto`, or `none` lol

Comment: @Yuniac This answer is very old. Today you have `unset` as a value that you can use everywhere.

Answer (score 31):

You can clear the max-height attribute by using the following css:

```
max-height:none;
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use

```
max-height: unset;
```

which resets a property to its inherited value if you are inheriting from its parent (will work as keyword inherit) and in case you are not inheriting it will resets to its initial value ( will work as keyword initial).

Comment: `unset` is not supported in IE11 as seem here: https://caniuse.com/css-unset-value
`max-height: none` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, if you're using JavaScript to style the element like `$el.style.maxHeight = '50px';` using `$el.style.maxHeight = 'none';` will not "reset" or "remove" the `50px`, it will simply override it. This means that if you try to "reset" the max height of an element using `$el.style.maxHeight = 'none';` it will apply the `none` value to the `max-height` property of the element, overriding any other valid `max-height` properties in CSS selection rules that match that element.

An example:

styles.css

```
.set-max-height { max-height: 50px; }
```

main.js

```
document.querySelectorAll('.set-max-height').forEach($el => {
  if($el.hasAttribute('data-hidden')){
    $el.style.maxHeight = '0px'; // Set max-height to 0px.
  } else {
    $el.style.maxHeight = 'none'; // 'Unset' max-height according to accepted answer.
});
```

To actually "unset" an inline style, you should use `$el.style.removeProperty('max-height');`.

To complete this for an entire style rule and not just a single element, you should first find the rule you want to modify, and then call the `removeProperty` function on that rule:

```
for(let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length; ++i){
  if(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].selectorText == '.set-max-height'){
    document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].style.removeProperty('max-height');
    break;
  }
}
```

You can find the `StyleSheet` and `CssRule` objects however you want, but for a simple application I'm sure the above would suffice.

Sorry for putting this as an answer, but I don't have 50 rep so I can't comment.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use either

```
max-height: none;
```

or

```
max-height: 100%;
```

**Note**: the second one is relative to the height of the containing block.

Comment: sorry but this is wrong, setting max-height: 100% is relative to the height of the containing block. So it limits the actual max height.