# CSS: how to overwrite (unset) previously set max-width property values

Tags: css

I have an image element that is styled to scale to the screen size within bound parameters defined in a `max-width`.

This styling works fine. However I home some images that need this maximum size (a percentage) to be removed on smaller screens (under 480px). To do this I need to "*unset*" a `max-width` value for the element set by the template structure.

HTML:

```
<figure class='image left'>
     <div class='boxShadowInner wide190'>
           <img src='/images/Bag.jpg' alt='text'>
     </div>
     <figcaption><strong>caption text</strong></figcaption>
</figure>
```

(The `boxShadowInner` class sets a feathered border around the image).

Template CSS (standard):

```
.image.left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 70vw;
    max-width: 90%;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto .5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Template CSS (max-width:480px):

```
.tableBox .image.left:not(.carrier) {
    max-width: none;    /** THIS LINE **/
    width: auto;
}
.image.right, .image.left {
    float: none;
}
```

Noting the line above; I need to **overwrite** the `max-width` property set at the base universal level for the style sheet.

## What I've tried already:

- `max-width: none;` as [suggested on this question (for `-height`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988145/how-to-unset-max-height) does not work in Firefox.
- The only `max-width` property that does work as intended (in Firefox) is: `max-width: max-content;` but as [stated on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width):

  > "*This is an experimental API that should not be used in production code.*"
- Other possible values for `max-width` do not give any change.
- `max-content` (*and similar keywords*) are seeingly not ready for production usage [according to caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-content).
- There are multiple images this rule needs to apply to so setting a value figure (280px, etc) is not a possible solution.
- I have tried `max-width: auto;` and Firefox tells me this is an invalid value.
- `!important` makes no difference.
- `max-width: initial` or `max-width: unset` also makes no difference.

## What I'm trying to achieve can be done with this:

```
.image.left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    /* max-width: 90%;     // Disabled */
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto .5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Screnshot of Firefox Developer Tools shows that it works perfectly when manually disabling the `max-width` rule setting, but I can't simulate this behavior using CSS rules:

[image]

## How do I overwrite the set `max-width` property to return it to browser default?

---

I made a fiddle but it doesn't seem to be working well with media queries..... (I don't use fiddles much I'm afraid)

https://jsfiddle.net/b8bsxtqu/7/

Comment: have you tried `auto` or `... !important`?

Comment: @YongQuan Yes I have tried both of these. I have updated my question clarifying this.

Comment: Could you include a demo so that we can try to reproduce this?

Comment: DId you try `max-width: initial` or `max-width: unset`?

Comment: Can dynamically setting `max-width` using `calc(...)` help in your case?

Comment: And of course instead of removing it bellow 480px you could just add it above 480px.

Comment: @Danield yes I have tried both of these

Comment: @xpy the rules apply to the whole template and I only want to not apply them to certain images. This can be done, but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: @YongQuan No, the images widths vary, unfortunately

Comment: @Danield I made a fiddle but it doesn't seem to be working well with media queries..... (I don't use fiddles much I'm afraid)

Comment: Are you setting max width on the image or figure? When set on the image, it's max width is dictated by it's natural width. To unset a max width it's `max-width: none`. If it's not working then it's an implementation thing. If you provide a complete fiddle we can better understand.

Comment: Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b8bsxtqu/5/

Comment: That's not a working fiddle, this is: https://jsfiddle.net/b8bsxtqu/3/

Comment: Thanks :-) question link updated

Comment: I simply can't reproduce this: see https://jsfiddle.net/9b3t4o8r/ - resize to see `max-width: none` working correctly - and I'm using firefox

Comment: @evu the max-width value is only used on the figure. the `img` is always 100% of te figure width. Disabling the `max-width` in developer tools makes the figure `inline-block` so only hugs the size of the natural image.

Comment: @Danield please see my above comment to evu. Cheers. It's not the `img` size but the `figure`

Comment: The value gets applied actually cause the width of that JSFiddle is set to 540 in my screen when I resize it I do get a working example where the width gets adjusted to 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was that the above `max-width` was being set on the container rather than on the `<img>` tag itself where the `<img>` tag had its own `max-` and `min-width` values set and removing/ adjusting these resolved this CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're after for your specific situation, but it's how I would approach it.

Instead of writing your CSS for your desktop/laptop and retrofitting it for smaller devices, write your CSS for the smallest devices first, then use media queries to 'enhance' the CSS (with media queries) and visuals for larger devices. This is what's known as a mobile first approach, or more accurately *smaller devices first*.

Reasons for developing this way.

1. You start with a simpler CSS code base.
2. It's easier to maintain and debug.
3. It keeps you in the mindset of keeping a priority on mobile browsers (have you looked at mobile usage statistics lately? [Whoa](http://gs.statcounter.com/platform-market-share/desktop-mobile-tablet).)
4. It puts the priority on content (where it should be)

Applying this to your situation, rather than "undoing" or "unsetting" a style for a small device.  Your CSS is written purposely without that style at the start because you're writing for small devices first. Then, using media queries you begin to add styles for larger, more accommodating devices.

In the snippet below you can see that the img has no max-width style applied to start. Then for devices with a min-width of 480px, you can specify your max-width.

```css
img {
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   img {
     max-width: 500px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<img src='https://placehold.it/900x500' alt='text'>
```

Comment: While I completely agree with your logic, I'm using a template CSS system that employs a system of universal rules and then subsets for different `@media` sizes. This is not mobile second, but more the issue I'm facing happens to be (through my choice) applicable in `<480px` screensizes.

Comment: @Martin If you simply need to revert it to it's default then `max-width: none` is what you're after (none being the default value). This works for me in firefox, chrome, etc.  If it's not working for you I'd suspect you have other styles at play that you might not be considering. https://jsfiddle.net/64otb4xh/

Comment: For some reason this usual method  isn't working on this situation.

Comment: @Martin This could be a matter of the initial CSS selector in your stylesheet being more explicit than the selector in your media query you're attempting to override it with.  For instance `.tableBox .image.left:not(.carrier)` is much more explicit than `.image-left` and trying to override the former with a media query stating the latter may not work.