# Reset or ignore a (max)width in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following code ([codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/mvOopZ))

```css
/******* NO ACCESS ********************/
.container {border: 1px solid green;}
.container > div {border: 1px solid red;}

.container .header {max-width: 50%;}
/**************************************/

.container.reset-header .header {max-width: auto;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4 header">col-4 modified to 50%</div>
</div>
<div class="container reset-header">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4 header">should be reset to col-4</div>
</div>
```

I have no acces to modify the inaccesible css, but I would like to reset the col-4 width with a "reset" class. I tried `auto`, `uset` or `inherit`, any of them didn't gave me the `33,33%` - as the `col-4` (or any other html attribute set in the code)

```
.container.reset-header .header {max-width: auto; }
.container.reset-header .header {max-width: unset; }
.container.reset-header .header {max-width: inherit;}
```

but it didn't help

Comment: Use @important!?

Comment: Is it actually overriding the css from before? Check that your css rule isn't being overridden due to specificity. (your's will be crossed out in dev tools)

Comment: there is no need to use !important, as already more important than other, the css is not overriden, you have the sample

Comment: max-width:none; [Same as for max-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988145/how-to-unset-max-height)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same value of `col-4` to reset the max-width.

Something like this work well:

```
.container.reset-header .header {
  max-width: 33.333333%; /* value of col-4 */
}
```

Edit:

What do you think about this solution, it's little bit tricky but visually you will have the correct rendering:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4 header">col-4 modified to 50%</div>
</div>
<div class="container reset-header">
  <div class="col-4">
    <span class="picture">col-4</span>
    <span class="header">should be reset to col-4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
/******* NO ACCESS ********************/
.container {border: 1px solid green;}
.container > div {border: 1px solid red;}

.container .header {max-width: 50%;}
/**************************************/
.container.reset-header > div{
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.container.reset-header span{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container.reset-header .header {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yes, but this is not "shading", I just set another value. suppose the col-4 is remplaced with col-6, it should follow

Answer (score 1):

`auto` is not a valid value for `max-width`

You can take `100%` or `inherit`

Comment: it should not be 100%, because is should take the other CSS code or to be as by default if any. In the concrete case it should be 33,33%

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `max-width:inherit;`

```css
/******* NO ACCESS ********************/
.container {border: 1px solid green;}
.container > div {border: 1px solid red;}

.container .header{max-width:50%;}
/**************************************/

.container.reset-header .header{max-width:inherit;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col md 4</div>
  <div class="col-4 header">usually is 50%</div>
</div>
<div class="container reset-header">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col md 4</div>
  <div class="col-4 header">on reset should be col-4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: as you can see from running your sample, it should be col-4, but instead is col-12...

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col-4</div>
  <div class="header">modified. If col-4 is being overriden, I don't see the purpose of .col-4 class</div>
</div>
<div class="container reset-header">
  <div class="col-4 picture">col-4</div>
  <div class="col-4">should be col-4. Remove the .header class and use a new class for whatever styles you need here and add the new class to the .header above</div>
</div>
```

With this you'd be able to clear all CSS code you're trying to use to override max-width.

I hope this helps

Comment: thank for answering. but did you try your suggestion in the codepen? it doesn't work.

Comment: @Serge, I see what you're trying to achieve, I feel like it's not possible without changing your html markup atleast

Comment: @Serge I have edited my answer, can you see if this works for you?

Comment: thanks. the question is however not about how to modity the HTML, but about how to update the CSS... if not possible this is also an answer... this is an example, but in production I can't modify the html...